# Node cannot find module ~/package.json (closed)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, git-bash

I'm trying to start my API with node but this error appears :

```
$ node ./.local/start.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/c/Users/$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P/Desktop/Stage/whasq-api-master/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at ConfigurationManager.getPackageConfig (C:\Users\$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P\Desktop\Stage\whasq-api-master\node_modules\@rduk\configuration\lib\manager.js:61:15)
    at getDocument (C:\Users\$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P\Desktop\Stage\whasq-api-master\node_modules\@rduk\configuration\lib\manager.js:74:31)
    at ConfigurationManager.getSection (C:\Users\$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P\Desktop\Stage\whasq-api-master\node_modules\@rduk\configuration\lib\manager.js:106:19)
    at ConfigurationManager.get (C:\Users\$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P\Desktop\Stage\whasq-api-master\node_modules\@rduk\configuration\lib\manager.js:93:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\$AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P\Desktop\Stage\whasq-api-master\index.js:14:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

The real problem is that the file package.json is present..

```
ls -a (at ~/Desktop/Stage/whasq-api-master)
./  ../  .circleci/  .gitignore  .local/  api/  config/  ecosystem.config.js  index.js  lib/  node_modules/  package.json  package-lock.json  README.md  sf_certificate/  templatesES.md
```

```
//package.json content

{
  "name": "whasq-api",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "whasq-api",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.11.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "standard --fix",
    "test": "exit 0"
  },
  "author": "WhASQ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@rduk/configuration": "^2.2.3",
    "@rduk/errors": "^1.3.1",
    "@rduk/logger": "^1.0.3",
    "@rduk/logger-winston-loggly-factory": "0.1.0",
    "@rduk/logger-winston-provider": "^1.0.4",
    "@rduk/message-broker": "^2.4.0",
    "@rduk/provider": "^3.1.3",
    "@rduk/tasks-orchestrator": "^0.1.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.256.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "csv": "^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "5.0.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.4.0",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "express-request-id": "^1.4.1",
    "helmet": "^3.15.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "orm": "^5.0.4",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "react-s3-uploader": "^4.8.0",
    "socket.io": "2.0.4",
    "socketio-jwt": "4.5.0",
    "standard": "11.0.1",
    "swagger-express-mw": "0.7.0",
    "winston": "2.4.0"
  },
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "keywords": []
}
```

I tried a lot of things, like switch versions of Node, delete modules then reinstall them, and other stuff like that but I cannot solve this problem.

I'm using those versions :
`npm 6.11.3` `node 8.11.1` and I'm using GitBash (i tried Powershell but no change)

(I tried every single version of Node (>=8.11.1) and the error is the same every time)

```
ls -a (at ~/Desktop/Stage/whasq-api-master/.local)
.env  start.js
```

```
//start.js content

require('dotenv').load({path: process.env.PWD + '/.local/.env'})
require('../')
```

```
//.env content

RDUK_CONFIG_PATH=config
RDUK_CONFIG_PREFIX=app
RDUK_CONFIG_EXT=.yaml
APP_PORT=6500
APP_SECRET=xxx
SF_SECRET=(hidden)
SF_CERTIFICATE=sf_certificate/public.pem
AMQP_ADDRESS=amqp://cawdev:cawdev@192.168.1.87:5672
LOGGLY_TOKEN=xxx
LOGGLY_SUBDOMAIN=xxx
LOGGLY_LOGIN=jessie
LOGGLY_PASSWORD=(hidden)
ES_ADDRESS=http://cawtest.net:9200/
DB_PROTOCOL=postgresql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5433
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_USER=esteban
DB_PASS=(hidden)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=(hidden)
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=(hidden)
AWS_REGION=eu-west-3
AWS_BUCKET=(hidden)
```

I also tried to move my repository at C:/ to avoid potential problems with my username ($AAU000-TFETR2QTBK6P) because I thought that name could be mistaken for an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue come from the way Windows interpret the npm library, I advise you to switch to a Linux or Mac environment..

Comment: Yeah i switched to Ubuntu 18.04 and the problem doesn't occur anymore.